# Feature reduction and class Imbalance handling which has to be performed first?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, imbalanced-data, data-preprocessing

I am working on the feature extraction and class imbalance problems, but need advice on which one to perform first? Feature reduction/selection or to handle class imbalance first?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: More information on the dataset would be helpful ? How many examples, features ? How imbalanced are the classes ? What kind models are you using ?